# What coordinate notation is this?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, coordinates, united-states

I have a shapefile with, for example, X_coords and Y_coords of 870058.5631 and 3226158.25 respectively. I want to convert these into decimal degrees in ArcGIS pro, but none of the input coordinate formats seem to work.

They are along the Louisiana Coastline. The spatial reference is NAD 1983 UTM Zone 15N.

Comment: They are along the Louisiana Coastline.  The spatial reference is NAD 1983 UTM Zone 15N

Comment: Thanks for your help, I wanted to convert these coordinates to GCS-WGS_1984 in order to use them in Google Earth Engine, but the ArcGIS tool I was using didn't seem to recognize them.  The answer below solved my problem.

Comment: I'm not an expert in northern hemisphere reference systems but have seen this sort of question before, a geographic transformation is required to adjust NAD to WGS, have a read of https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005929 about selecting the correct transformation for your area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the 'Calculate Geometry Attributes' tool to accomplish this.  The important part is setting a coordinate system appropriately. Your source coordinate is a projected coordinate system (using meters as the units).  Set the output to a geographic one (uses degrees as units).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.